# Define Elements as Method, Constant, or Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can group up reusable elements either as a constant, method, or component:

```
const someElementsConst = <div><p>Some Elements</p></div>
const getSomeElements = () => <div><p>Some Elements</p></div>
const SomeElementsComponent = () => <div><p>Some Elements</p></div>
```

and then use them like this..

```
<div>
   {someElementsConst}
   {getSomeElements()}
   <SomeElementsComponent/>
</div>
```

My question is this: Is there any right or wrong answer to which of these approaches I should use and when, in terms of good practice, under-the-hood mechnisms, performance, etc?

Comment: Such questions are meant for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I suggest reading https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html
Performance wise it shouldn't make a difference at all.
In general its about personal preference and code writing.

Also reusing an element as a constant means no variables can be passed to it & no methods such as Component did update can run on it.
The other 2 way's allow this and are somewhat the same thing written in a different way because Components Can Be Classes or Functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it depends on what you want to render.

In the example you gave, you only render simple html tags with no chance to change over renders. So basically it does not change anything whether you choose to render it as a constant, a function call or a JSX component.

However, for more complex components (with state management, side effects etc) :

> You need to use JSX (or React.createElement) when rendering components rather than simply calling the function. That way, any hooks that are used can be registered with the instance of the component that React creates.

source : https://kentcdodds.com/blog/dont-call-a-react-function-component